# Python Multiprocessing with Selenium

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a question, and I've searched really long and haven't found anything.
So I want to use Selenium with Multiprocessing, so that 2 Functions, or maybe more, can work at the same time. But I want It to be on the same driver. As example, Function 1 does stuff, and when something certain happens on the website Function 2 should start, and they should work simultaneously
on the same driver/website/instance of Selenium.
Would something like that be possible?
(If I should explain It more In detail, I can do that.)

Edit: Here's some code I've tried:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from multiprocessing import Process
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches" , ["enable-automation"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path = './chromedriver')

def func1():
    driver.get('https://test.com')

def func2():
    driver.get('https://test2.com')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=func1)
    p1 = Process(target=func2)
    p.start()
    p1.start()
```

But this'll just start 3 Chrome Windows, one with test.com another one with test2.com and another one with nothing and the URL data

Comment: Check this info about Threading, I think it will help you.
https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

Also provide some code about what you have tried to do

Comment: @VasylYovdiy Added some Code about what I've tried.

Comment: Selenium web drivers are definitely **not** thread safe and I suspect (although I'm not certain) that you'd have issues trying to share a driver across multiple sub-processes. What is not clear from your question is why you seem to think that you'd somehow benefit from using a single driver instance. Why not instantiate a discrete driver for each sub-process?

Comment: @DarkKnight I'm working on something where you can only have one running Instance with the same Account, so I don't really have any other option.

Comment: In that case I suggest using multi-threading in conjunction with a queue. Instantiate the driver instance and put() it on the queue. Each thread can then do a (blocking) get() on the queue to get the driver, do whatever it needs to do with it then put() it back on the queue. In that way you'll have a single driver and can guarantee that no two threads will be trying to use it concurrently

Comment: @DarkKnight Maybe I haven't understood you right, but I need the second Function to check something every second, so I'm not really sure how I'd do that, maybe you could give me a code example?

Comment: If you're thinking about doing a driver.get(URL) once per second then you should think again especially if the URL has a lot of Ajax-style work going on. The point being that the target URL page may not even load fully in 1 second!

Comment: @DarkKnight The driver.get(URL) was just a test, I need It to do something else/check something every 1 - 2 seconds, that's why I wanted multiprocessing because It could happen simultaneously

Comment: It is not possible to run parallel actions with shared driver. You will get a mess. The only way to paralellize actions is to have two isolated driver objects.

Comment: @AlexeyR. So It's Impossible to achieve what I'm trying?

Comment: I think you need to describe your use-case in more detail. After every comment we get a new caveat and/or design consideration.

Comment: @DarkKnight So let's say every 5 seconds something new gets added to the website, and everytime that happens, It needs to be detected, while another functions already running, so they can simultaneously run. In best case Scenario no Function should be stopped, but If It needs to stop the First Function sometimes that's not a problem.

Comment: do you just want multiple windows in the same browser session?

Comment: @DMart No, let's say I open a website, and Function 1 does stuff with the website, while Function 2 simultaneously checks for something on the Website that could get added any second, that's why I need a second Function Instead of just one because It'll go away fast and I need to check for It every second, but I guess It's not possible, as Alexey R. said.